# Type error: cannot read property 'rows' of null when deleting a row using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript

```
function deleteRow(tableID) 
      {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(collct_table_body);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox&& true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
```

But when I try to delete a row using this it shows an error "cannot read property 'rows' of null type error"

Is there any error in this javascript Im using?Can some one help me out?

Comment: Instead of editing the question to show [solved], you should accept the answer below to indicate that solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be more constructive instead of just saying "I rolled back your edit because what you did is against our guidelines." Or just rolling back with no explanation. I didn't intend it to sound as harsh as I can see now it is - my apologies.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the quotes

```
document.getElementById("collct_table_body");
```

or, may be this is a variable (which I don't see in your code, global var?? we will never know)

```
var collct_table_body = "someID";
```

Comment: Note 1 : When ever a Id or a class is send as parameters always enclose in quotes.
Note 2: Since its getElementById() the id doesn't require a #.